# How to Start the Vuforia AR sample App android?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am following the `Vuforia` and I have run the samples, It's working fine  but if I want to start the our own app so could you help me how to start the app.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on issues you're facing?

Comment: @harism what Vuforia has provided samples app working fine but if i am start the our own app i am not able to start the app using the Vuforia

Comment: To make your question constructive better and sooner provide the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Roman C  Actually i'm new to the VUforia So i don't know the how to start the my own sample application ,So Could you  help me.

Comment: what kind of App you want to start with It brief it 1st

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37140255/5021501

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps to integrate vuforia with your android project.

1)copy **vuforia.jar** and **armeabi-v7** folder that contains **libvuforia.so** and paste it on your libs folder of your project.

2)right click on your android project and go to **build path>cofigure build path** and select libraries tab and add vuforia.jar file.

this will work now you can easy to use vuforia functions.

if you want to create your own marker then you have to log in in https://developer.vuforia.com/targetmanager and create project and then download .xml file and .dat file and then integrate that file with your android project

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio 2.3.3
1. Copy vuforia.jar and libvuforia.so in your libs folder
2. In your app, right click and select open module settings
3. Click On the dependencies and '+' sign to add "jar dependency"
4. Select vuforia.jar and click Ok

Done!