# Installing Vuforia in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality, vuforia

Can anyone give me some instructions of how I'm supposed to install Vuforia in Android Studio? I'm making a new app and I need to use augmented reality with Vuforia. Hope you can help me!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe this can help  http://stackoverflow.com/q/20334041/5885018

Comment: the answer of Dhana Sekaran in this link worked for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334041/using-android-studio-with-vuforia

Comment: @SohaAbuhamam This is vuforia's official answer but the link is not officially available now since vuforia purchased by PTC. thats why I share my offline content. My purpose is to help someone only

Comment: I have follow steps of this http://www.paolomoschini.it/2015/11/30/trying-vuforia-with-android-studio/ blog and My sample is running. May be It will help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You need to follow following Steps:**

- Read our Getting Started Guide for instructions on setting up the
  Java SDK, Android SDK and NDK:

  https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk
- Make sure you have installed the latest version available of Android
  Studio from:

  http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
- Use the Android SDK Manager (from within Android Studio) to get the
  latest Android SDK and Android Platform and Build tools
- Launch Android Studio
- **Select File - > Import Project** ... and browse to the root directory
  of the sample Vuforia project you want to open
- Proceed in the Import Wizard dialog (click Next, Next) until you
  reach a page with this message:

  1. "Alternatively, you can fill in the actual path map in the table below":
  2. click to edit
  3. enter the actual path to the Vuforia.jar library (which is located under your **vuforia_install_dir/build/java/vuforia**)
- In the Project view, right-click on the Project and expand the view
  hierarchy so to locate the **Vuforia.ja**r under **app > src > main**
- right-click on Vuforia.jar to open the context menu
- click on the **"Add as library**..." option in the context menu
- Alternatively, if you cannot locate the Vuforia.jar in your project
  hierarchy:
- right-click on the Project and select, "Open Module Settings"

  1. select "App"
  2. then select the "Dependencies" tab
  3. Click on the "+" button to Add a File Dependency and browse to the
     Vuforia.jar file
- Create a folder called **"jniLibs"** under the **"app/src/main"** folder under your Android Studio project directory
- Copy the "armeabi-v7a" folder (including the libVuforia.so file
  located inside it) from the **"vuforia_install_dir/build/lib"** to the
  **"app/src/main/jniLibs" folder**

the resulting directory structure under your project root should be:

```
/app
  /src
     /main
        /jniLibs
             /armeabi-v7a
                 /**libVuforia.so**
```

- If your project includes a **"jni"** folder, move it to a location
  outside of your project (otherwise Android Studio may attempt to
  compile the sources in that folder and may fail)
- Clean and rebuild the project
- Run the app on your device

Best Luck :)

Comment: This looks like something you copied from somewhere else. Do you have a link to the original source? Where did you get it from? Thanks!

Comment: This vuforia's official answer but the link is not officially available now since vuforia purchased by PTC. Still if you want official link just go to : https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Installing-the-Vuforia-Android-SDK

Comment: I couldn't find the mention of the directory `/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a` on their official docs though

Comment: Its my extra addition to simplify code structure, as I mention above : Create a folder called "jniLibs" under the "app/src/main" folder under your Android Studio project directory. Otherwise you can directly paste sample code into the "samples" folder

Comment: Here's one more step I needed to make these instructions work (and they did!) in 2021: Either avoid updating to Gradle 4.0, or remove a certain line from your app gradle. More discussion here: https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Release_Notes/Vuforia-SDK-Release-Notes.html

Answer (score 1):

answer from [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/sample-app-failing-build-android-studio) and work for me:

(Seems like the project needs access to the Vuforia.jar file and can't access it outside of the sample folder(?))

So,

1. copy the Vuforia.jar file from the folder \vuforia-sdk-android-x-x-x\build\java\vuforia to a folder in the sample project, e.g. to \samples\app\libs
   (it's important it's in the "\app" path, so you can find it in the next step)
2. in Android SDK hit F4 (or right click on the app folder in the project structure and click on "Open Module Settings".
   Select the tab "dependencies", click on the "+" to add a dependency and select "2 File dependency".
   Now select the above path and file ((\samples\app) \libs\Vuforia.jar) and the project will run just fine...

Good luck.