# Installing Vuforia on Android Studio - gradle error

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, vuforia

Good Morning,

I'm relatively new on Android Studio development. 
I'm having some problems installing the Vuforia and its samples on Android Studio.

I've followed two different tutorials:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GG8yTlrt0hw
http://www.paolomoschini.it/2015/11/30/trying-vuforia-with-android-studio/

I've also tried the tutorial: [Installing Vuforia in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699579/installing-vuforia-in-android-studio), which is similar to the *paolomoschini*.

No matter which tutorial I followed I still get the same error.

It shows the following message:

- Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com' You may need to adjust the proxy settings in gradle.
- "Enable gradle 'offline mode' and sync project".

Hereupon I have no idea where should I start in order to solve this error?

Any help will be extremely appreciated.
Ricardo Gomes

Answer (score 2):

1. open your `build.gradle` file
2. under `dependencies`' `classpath` section, update the gradle version to the latest

the above 2 steps solved the same problem i faced while installing Vuforia's sample files on Android Studio.

hope this helps :)